# Different wg.Done() causes WaitGroup is reused before previous Wait has returned

Tags: go

I am testing `sync.WaitGroup`, if I put `defer wg.Done()` in the begining of the function, like this:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "sync"
        "time"
)

func worker(wg *sync.WaitGroup, id int) error {
    defer wg.Done() // put here cause error
    fmt.Printf("Worker %v: Finished\n", id)
    if true {
        return nil
    }

    return nil
}

var wg sync.WaitGroup // I should put `wg` outside of this function
func callWorker(i int){
    fmt.Println("Main: Starting worker", i)
    fmt.Printf("Worker %v: Finished\n", id)
    wg.Add(1)
    go worker(&wg, i)
    wg.Wait()
}

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        go callWorker(i)
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 60)
    fmt.Println("Main: Waiting for workers to finish")

    fmt.Println("Main: Completed")
}
```

I will get `WaitGroup is reused before previous Wait has returned` in some cases, like this

[image]

but if I put `defer wg.Done()` in the end of function, it runs successfully, why?

```
func worker(wg *sync.WaitGroup, id int) error {
    
    fmt.Printf("Worker %v: Finished\n", id)
    if true {
        return nil
    }
    defer wg.Done() // put here, it is ok
    return nil
}
```

Comment: `wg.Done()` is not called in the second implementation of `worker`.  The function returns before the `defer` statement.

Comment: Why did not other goroutines block?

Comment: The example you are testing wait groups with are pretty obtuse. Using goroutines and wait groups where they aren't needed may confuse you. Using a wait group variable at the package scope is a bad idea, too, as you found out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docs state](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#WaitGroup.Add) that "If a `WaitGroup` is reused to wait for several independent sets of events, new Add calls must happen after all previous Wait calls have returned"

You are calling `wg.Done()` in some goroutines before calling `wg.Add(1)` in others, which is not allowed, as stated by the docs.  You need to call `wg.Add` before you start all those goroutines, and you might as well just call it once, `wg.Add(1000)`

The reason your other code works is that it never calls `wg.Done()`, you have

```
if true {
     return nil
}
defer wg.Done()
```

so you always return without reaching the defer statement, so there are never any calls to `wg.Done()`.

Do this:

```golang
func callWorker(i int){
    fmt.Println("Main: Starting worker", i)
    // you cannot call Add here because Done has been called in other goroutines
    go worker(&wg, i)
    wg.Wait()
}

func main() {
    wg.Add(1000) // <---- You must call Add before Done is called in any goroutine
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        go callWorker(i)
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 60)
    fmt.Println("Main: Completed")
}
```

Comment: @Sean Yes , it did not call `wg.Done` in the second implementation of worker, but why did not other goroutines block?

Comment: `WaitGroup is reused before previous Wait has returned`, I think this error is mostly because call `wg.Done` before `wg.Add`, but in my codes, I use `wg.Add` before `wg.Done` and if a gorutine does not call `wg.Done`, others gorutine will block.

Comment: In each goroutine you call wg.Add before wg.Done, but some goroutines call wg.Done before you call wg.Add in other goroutines.

Comment: You need to call wg.Add in all goroutines before you call wg.Done in any goroutine

Comment: I do not understand what did you mean, for example, I have 10 goroutines to call `wg.Add` and `wg Done`, `wg.Add` is before `wg.Done` in each goroutine, after I call 10 times `wg.Add`, the value is 10, and there will be 10 times `wg.Done`, there is not the eleventh `wg.Done`

Comment: It does not matter that wg.Add is before wg.Done in each goroutine

Comment: You must call wg.Add in all goroutines before you call wg.Done in any goroutine

Comment: That is how it must work.  Because you are not doing that, you are getting errors.

Comment: I've added code to illustrate

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if `Wait()` is called on a waitgroup, it is not allowed to reuse this waitgroup and call `Add()` on it again until the `Wait()` call is returned (see [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#WaitGroup.Add)). In this programm the callWorker function is itself a go routine and all callWorker functions are running concurrently. Without waiting for each other they try to call `Add()` while a previous `Wait()` call isn't finished.

The first workers yield results without error because their `Wait()` call is luckily returned before the next `Add()` call, a classical race condition.

If you want the workers to run concurrently you have to move `Wait()` and `Add()` out of the callWorker function. `Wait()` must be called after the for-loop. And `Add()` should be called inside the loop before callWorker, otherwise the program will finish before callWorker has a chance to add something to the waitgroup and hence `Wait()` has nothing to wait for. There is no need for time.Sleep in `main()`, too.

```
func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go callWorker(i)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Main: Waiting for workers to finish")

    fmt.Println("Main: Completed")
}
```